# Cant move the menus in the header upwards to align with the logo

Tags: html, css

[Header with logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94LzE.png)

1. i want to align home, etc with the logo, but i think the logo is occupying all the space on top of the menu-headers and i dont know how to reduce it, i've already tried the margin-left or right and also padding but it doesnt help.
   i also want to know if it is a bad practice to have negative CSS rules or if there is any bad practices in my code so far.
   sorry for the bad english, i`m not a native

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Heloisa Antoniely │ Makeup</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Makeup.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="author" content="Thiago Marvin">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=STIX+Two+Math&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="main-header">
            <div class="Logo">
                <img src="photos/Logo.png.png" alt="Makeup" class="center">
            </div>
            <div class="social">

            </div>
            <div class="header-menus">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="">Home</a>
                    <a href="">Contato</a>
                    <a href="">Portfólio</a>
                    <a href="">Localização</a>
                </li>
            </ul>   
        </div>
    </header>
    <section>
        
    </section>

</body>
</html>
```

```
body{
    background-color: #137B77;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
header{
    background-color: #45a29e;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    justify-content: baseline;
}
.center{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 15%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-bottom: -124px;
    margin-top: -65px;
}
.main-header{
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 62px;
}
.header-menus{
    padding-top: 0;
}
.header-menus ul li {
    list-style: none;
    color: #000000;
}
.header-menus ul li a{
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding-left: 30px;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 2.0;
    font-family: 'STIX Two Math', serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `div` elements are block elements, they take all available horizontal space of the parent element, i.e. a complete "line".

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements

I would recommend using `display: flex` on the `.main-header` class. By default the child elements will be arranged in a row (`flex-direction: row`).

The `align-items` property can be used to arrange the elements vertically.

See https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.main-header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/u3gv6s7f/

Comment: yeah that helps, but the home menu is in the right side of the logo now, any tips to set it to the left?

Comment: You could move the nodes around. By default the rendering order of nodes is as defined in the DOM tree. If you move the `div` element by class `header-menus` to the top within its parent container, it will be displayed on the left side.

See https://jsfiddle.net/pctb7vze/

Comment: mate, thanks so much for the patience i`m really glad.

Comment: I'm glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Give the logo a width of x px. That will give it a set size. You can do width=100% and make sure you style the container div as a inline-block or use flex-box in order to set its size straight.

```
.main-header {
    display: flex;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

That should make every element inside the header display on a row.
Look more into flex-box in order to understand it well. https://flexboxfroggy.com/ is a good resource.

Comment: This kinda work but the home menus are in the right side now :/

Comment: btw thanks for the flexboxfroggy, it really helps a lot to understand it

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox in main div which wraps logo and links

```
.main-header{
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 62px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; //you can do also space-between or space-evenly
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: that work but the home menus is in the right side now, any tips to set it to the left ?

Comment: Yes you can give justify-content: flex-start then for header-menus you can give margin-left to separete them from logo. If it does not work in the way that you want, give width values also for div header-menus and Logo

Comment: thanks man you also helped me to understand better the overall